# Updating table in Access depending on another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a question about
I have two tables
One is like

ID | Name

---

1  | AAAA

2  | BBBB

3  | CCCC...

another one is

ID | Age | Gender

---

1  | 15  | F

3  | 18  | M

2  | 21  | F

etc..
now i want to get values from column "Name" and replace with column ID.. it should looks like

ID    | Age | Gender

---

AAAA  | 15  | F

CCCC  | 18  | M

BBBB  | 21  | F

Comment: Please add more detail - are you trying to write a query?  Create a new table?  Update an existing table's schema, or just the data?

Comment: I am updating existing table, with values of ID, now i need to update those fields with "Names" which are in column next to IDs in another table

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace the ID's in Table2 with the Name field from Table1, I'd recommend an update query. Something like:

```
UPDATE Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID SET Table2.ID = [Name];
```

The only thing is you need to make sure the ID fields are Short Text in both tables first, otherwise you're going to run into a type mismatch error.